# Is it possible to use PHPUnit @depends without calling tearDown and setUp between dependent cases?

Tags: php, phpunit

For example, the action in `test1` stores data externally* which `test2` then performs an assertion on, but `tearDown` deletes that data thus breaking `test2`. Cache deletion can't be removed from `tearDown` since other tests depend on it. This question is asking if there is a way to skip setUp/tearDown between dependent cases while maintaining the functionality of `@depends` (which skips the second test if the first test fails instead of the second test failing).

```
public function tearDown() {
    // delete cache
}

// verify the expected data was retrieved from an uncached source
public function test1() {
    $sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    $data = $sut->getDataAndCache();
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $data);
    return $sut;
}

// verify the expected data was cached
/** @depends test1 */
public function test2($sut) {
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $sut->getCache());
}
```

*We'll call these integration tests since they interact with an external system.

Answer (score 20):

In the setup method you can check if the test has `hasDependencies()` and then skip the setup procedures:

```
public function setUp()
{
    if (!$this->hasDependencies()) {
        // do setup tasks 
    }
}
```

Comment: This method was added in PHPUnit 4.0.0. For earlier versions, see Mike Henry's solution below (setting static flag to prevent setUp and tearDown execution).

Comment: I don't think this method is part of the latest version of PHPUnit.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an alternative to this in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options.

The first one would be to isolate these two tests into a separate test class. That way your tearDown in other classes will not interfere.

You still might want to get rid of the cache after the test. Well, testing the cache deletion could be a step of itself. But PHPUnit also offers two static methods that are run before the test class starts testing, and after all tests in the class have been run: `setUpBeforeClass()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` (see http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/fixtures.html).

On the other hand, the easiest way out would be to combine the two test methods into ONE function. You are already in some kind of trouble with violating the single responsibility principle by naming a function getData**AND**Cache, so there is little benefit in separating the test into two functions.

Comment: These are good suggestions. Maybe it could be good to split `getDataAndCache()` into two separate methods, though it would put more responsibility on the caller.

Comment: A good approach to caching is using the decorator pattern. That basically splits the two responsibilities into two classes - the original class only deals with the business logic, and the decorating cache class only deals with caching, eventually passing the call into the original class, intercepting the result and put it into the cache. That way you could independently test whether your caching logic works.

Comment: Just as a word of warning: In case you have tets annotated with `@dataProvider myDataProviderMethodXXX`, despite of the name `setUpBeforeClass()` this static method will be run actually AFTER any  call to methods `myDataProviderMethodXXX()`. So the order of PHPUnit initialization is: 1. Instantiate by calling constructor of `MyUnitTest()` 2. Run all of the data-provider methods (eg. `myDataProvider()` 3. run static `setUpBeforeClass()`. 4. Now for each test method run: `setUp()`,  `testMyTestMethod()` , `tearDown()` 5. and I guess somewhere in the end `tearDownAfterClass()`. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack for you for **PHPUnit 9.5**:

```php
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp()

        // prevent from running for tests with @depends
        if (!empty($this->requires())) { 
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
```

It works for what the question asks for.

**However,** I said this is a hack so keep in mind:

- `tearDown` is still being run - and it destroys the test object instance (a.k.a. `$this`), rollbacks all of the transactions if you `use DatabaseTransactions;` etc.
- If you assign common variables to `$this` - they will be gone!
- `parent::setUp()` if you're in Laravel or a similar framework, boots the application, that's why you most probably still have to call it every time as in the example.

So in short, **it's not a good idea** most probably.

Maybe consider using a PHPUnit wrapper like [PestPHP](https://pestphp.com) for syntaxic sugar like that, I just wish it were more time-tested and not probable to be abandoned in say ten years time...

Answer (score 0):

One idea I have is to use a static field such as `is_depends` which would be set to true in `test1` and false in `test2` and `setUp` and `tearDown` would check the value of `is_depends` before running. E.g.

```
private static is_depends;

public function setUp() {
    if (self::$is_depends) return;
    // do setup that shouldn't be done between dependencies
}

public function tearDown() {
    if (self::$is_depends) return;
    // delete cache
}

// verify the expected data was retrieved from an uncached source
public function test1() {
    $sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    $data = $sut->getDataAndCache();
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $data);
    self::$is_depends = true;
    return $sut;
}

// verify the expected data was cached
/** @depends test1 */
public function test2($sut) {
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $sut->getCache());
    self::$is_depends = false;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think this will work as expected if you have test3 and test1 fails, as the is_dependency is not reset to false.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to perform most of the arrange and act steps in both tests. Then there wouldn't be a need to maintain external state between test1 and test2. The `@depends` annotation would still cause test2 to be skipped if test1 failed. If the arrange and act steps were more complex, they could be extracted to a separate method and called by both tests.

Here's an example of the updated test2 method (using test1 from the original question):

```
// verify the expected data was cached
/** @depends test1 */
public function test2($sut) {
    $data = $sut->getDataAndCache();
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $sut->getCache());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same case as in original question but dependant tests needed to be in a state left by one single test. I.e `test11` and `test12` needed both the db state of `test1`.

PHPUnit's `@depends` did not suite for me either as setUp was run before each test, meaning return value of `test1` for `test11` and `test12` was invalid because it did not exist in db any more.

So I tried `if (!$this->hasDependencies()) { /* do setUp tasks */ }` in `setUp` as [proposed above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919202/2494723). This did not work either because each dependant test (`test11` and `test12` in my case) left db in its own state.

I ended up with no magic but made `test1` re-usable by returning a value. A modified version of `@depends` functionality, sort of:

```php
class Test {
    function setUp() {
        // normal setUp, no magic
    }

    // Test that others depend on, return its value
    function test1(): int {
        // assert record being inserted, assign id to $id
        return $id;
    }

    function test11() {
        $id = $this->testInsert();
        // assert something by $id and possibly modify db
    }

    function test12() {
        $id = $this->testInsert();
        // assert something else by $id and possibly modify db
    }

    // ...
}
```

Maybe this helps someone.